# card token Stripe using postman

Tags: postman, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a stripe card token using postman. I am making a post request to https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens
In the header i added: - Authorization : Bearer MY SECRET KEY
- Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

For the body i choose form-data, refer to the screenshot for values and key.
However i am getting the error below

"error": {
"code": "parameter_missing",
"doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-missing",
"message": "You must supply either a card, customer, PII data, bank account, or account legal entity to create a token. If you're making this request with a library, be sure to pass all of the required parameters for creating a token. If you're making this request manually, be sure your POST parameters begin with the token type. For example, a PII token would require `pii[personal_id_number]`, while an account token would require a parameter beginning with `account[legal_entity]`. See the API reference for more information

CAN SOMEONE PLEASE HELP ME?

I tried to change the body to x-www-form-urlencoded, but getting different. I am just trying to generate card token/or card id
[image: Bodyvalues]

[image: ScreenshotOfValues]

Comment: @qichuan click on the Bodyvalues to open the screenshots

Answer (score 0):

You missing the Authorization part in Postman.
This is documentation in [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication)

[image]

```
POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens
```

[image]

This Option (Authorization Bearer token type) will be added to the header automatically.

[image]

Body section: x-www-form-urlencoded

```
card[number]:4242424242424242
card[exp_month] : 5
card[exp_year] : 2024
card[cvc] : 314
```

[image]

The Access Token copy from my dashboard's API public key.

```
https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys
```

[image]